# Firing onchange event to access input field with Selenium & Webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to add a date in an input field. When I use webdriver to access the the input field, using this code:

```
 driver.find_element_by_class_name('input[class=".textbox-text.validatebox-text.textbox-prompt"]')
```

I get an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class selector","selector":"input[class=".textbox-text.validatebox-text.textbox-prompt"]"}
```

When I run a get_attribute('class') loop, I can see this class:

```
easyui-datebox base datebox-f combo-f textbox-f
```

but when I try selecting using this code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('input[class=".easyui-datebox.base.datebox-f.combo-f.textbox-f"]')
```

I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"input[class=".easyui-datebox.base.datebox-f.combo-f.textbox-f"]"}
```

this is the html code:

```
<td width="114" nowrap="">
    <input type="text" id="FROMDATE" class="easyui-datebox base datebox-f combo-f textbox-f" data-options="keyHandler: {
        up: function(e){},
        down: function(e){},
        left: function(e){},
        right: function(e){},
        enter: function(e){handleReturn(e);},
        query: function(q,e){}
    }, 
        onChange:function(newVal,oldVal){if (ignoreOnChange) return false; resetDateRange_150();}" style="width: 114px; display: none;" textboxname="FROMDATE" comboname="FROMDATE">
        <span class="textbox combo datebox" style="width: 112px; height: 20px;">
        <span class="textbox-addon textbox-addon-right" style="right: 0px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="textbox-icon combo-arrow" icon-index="0" tabindex="-1" style="width: 18px; height: 20px;"></a></span>
        <input type="text" class="textbox-text validatebox-text textbox-prompt" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 18px; padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; width: 86px;">
        <input type="hidden" class="textbox-value" name="FROMDATE" value="">
```

the input field im trying to access:

```
<input type="text" class="textbox-text validatebox-text textbox-prompt" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 18px; padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; width: 86px;">
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 driver.find_element_by_class_name('input[class=".textbox-text.validatebox-text.textbox-prompt"]')
```

In above code, the value specified for class name doesn't seem to be valid.

*input[class=".textbox-text.validatebox-text.textbox-prompt"]* seems to be a **css selector syntax**. However, it would require one correction. 
The valid css selector is either :

*input.textbox-text.validatebox-text.textbox-prompt*

**or**

*input[class='textbox-text validatebox-text textbox-prompt']*

I would suggest using one of the following instead :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.textbox-text.validatebox-text.textbox-prompt")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[class='textbox-text validatebox-text textbox-prompt']")
```